# Qualtitative explanation for the link between low magnitude of high z supernova and accelerated expansion

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, big-bang

Is there any explanation on a qualitative level why we can see in the observed magnitude vs. redshift z plot that the universe is expanding accelerated? See for example here:
http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/univacc.html

The observed magnitude is, if the absolute magnitude is well know as it is the case for Supernova 1a, a measure for the distance. The redshift z is a measure for how much the object hast moved relative to us., i.e. also some kind of distance indicator. My problem is that I can't get together how we now conclude that we have an accelerated expansion, besides the best fit has $\Omega_{\Lambda}\neq 0$. Any help or link would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very nice paper exactly on this topic, where the expressions describing the fit curves are derived: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9906447v1 If you have a look at the final expression (formula (6.5) on page 8), you will agree, that the relation between $\Omega_\Lambda$ and the luminosity is hard to describe by words.

However, you can try to think about this in the following way: Comparing an accelerated universe with a non-accelerated universe which at present time have both the same size (or, to be more precise, the same value of the scale factor $a_0$) and the same expansion ratio (or, to be more precise, the same value of the Hubble constant $H_0$), we can ask ourselves, which one was smaller at a given time in the past, say 10 billions of years ago. If you think about it, you will come to the conclusion, that an accelerated universe was **larger** 10 billions of years ago than a non-accelerated universe. You can have a look at the graphics from figure 2 on page 5 of the paper linked above and compare graphics for different values of $\Omega_\Lambda$. For instance compare the $y$-values of the universes $A$ and $E$ at early times. $A$ has $\Omega_\Lambda=0$ while $E$ has $\Omega_\Lambda=0.9$. As you can see the size of $A$ is smaller than the size of $E$ as the curve of $A$ is below the curve of $E$ for all $t-t_0<0$.

If you agree to this, the rest is easy. Given a SNIA that emitted a photon some billions of years ago, we know that the ratio $a_0/a(t)$ of the universe's size at the time of emission and today is **smaller** in an accelerated universe than in a non-accelerated one. Therefore, the redshift of the light will also be **smaller**, since the redshift $z$ is given by $1+z=a_0/a(t)$. Therefore, for given apparent magnitude (i.e. also given the current distance), the points in the graph that you linked in your question will be shifted to the **left** in an accelerated universe as compared to a non-accelerated one.

Comment: The paper you cite is awesome

Comment: Glad you liked it, I also liked it very much when I was writing a term paper on SNIA some years ago.

Comment: One small question: If the universe was smaller in the past for an accelerated universe, why should $a(t)/a_0$ be bigger? Maybe you mean $z+1=a_0/a(t)$?

Comment: Furthermore shouldn't points with a given apparent magnitude with bigger z be shifted to the right instead of to the left??

Comment: You're absolutely right, I mixed up today's time and the time of emission. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: And answering your last comment, I now realize that I again argued in the wrong direction (this happened several time already...). I will edit the answer once more.

Comment: I hope, now all steps are correct, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Thanks again for your thoughts. Is the logic leading to a larger universe for an accelerating universe something like: If today the universe expands with a given speed, i.e. $H_0$, an accelerating universe must have been expanding slower in the past, because the expansion speed is rising up to the value today, and this leads to a bigger universe at a given point in the past?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken again - yes.